# Does anyone know anymore Shorthand Action Script 3?

Tags: flash, actionscript, shorthand

I'm used to using the if else shorthand:

var = (if statement) ? 'something' : 'something else';

Are there any other short hand methods available?

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if this fits into what you're asking, but this also works:

```
var myVar:String = someStrThatMightBeNull || "default value if that other value is null";
```

So, if the first value to the right of the assignment operator is null/undefined, it will use the literal string.

Comment: Those are called guard operators. Both && and || work like this in ActionScript.

Answer (score 5):

```
var myArray:Array = new Array();
```

Can be replaced with:

```
var myArray:Array = [];
```

Same goes for objects:

```
var myObj:Object = new Object();
```

Can be replaced with:

```
var myObj:Object = {};
```

Answer (score 4):

```
x ||= 5; // set x to 5 if x evaluates to false
x || someMethod(); // call someMethod if x evaluates to false
x && someMethod(); // call someMethod if x evaluates to true
```

Comment: It's just a shame that `||=` seems to compile to `x = x ? x : 5;` and thus reassigns itself. And flex compiler 4.6 (I think) spits over `||=` completely.
Ref: http://www.tillschneidereit.de/2011/10/22/mario-mushroom-now-with-80-less-awesome/

Comment: Indeed, what we want is `x || (x = 5)` and not `x = (x || 5)`

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, that is not shorthand for an if/else statement.  That's a ternary operator called a conditional operator.

Notice that while these do the same thing, they read differently:

```
// if the condition is true, we do something... maybe many things
if (condition) {
  var = 'something';
} else {
  var = 'something else';
}

// reads more clearly as an assignment based upon a condition
var = (condition) ? 'something' : 'something else';
```

In many cases it's fine to think of it as shorthand.  Over time, your brain will instincitvely select a conditional operator where appropriate; but as you're just getting your feet wet you'll find the conditional operator to be a great way to express code more succinctly.

Comment: That "if statement" should be called "condition" for clarity.

Comment: -1 You're really splitting hairs with your statement about strict equivalence and this could throw some developers off.  If you clarify your statement, I'll remove my downvote.